# How to check if the field in the class is serializable?

Tags: c#, serialization

I am working on my own implementation of JSON serializer and I need to get all serializable fields of the class.

For example, I have class like this:

```
[Serializable]
class TestClass
{
    public int i;
    public string s;

    [NonSerialized]
    public string ignore;
}
```

So I don't want to serialize `ignore`. In this code I try to print all serializable fields:

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(TestClass).GetFields())
{
    if (field.FieldType.IsSerializable) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine (field.Name);
    }
}
```

Eventually `ignore` is printed as well as others. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't your attribute be [NonSerialized] instead?

Comment: @JamesDev Yes, it's a typo. But with [NonSerialized] it is also not working as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldType.IsSerializable` checks if the type of the field is serializable, not the field itself. Instead, use [`IsNotSerialized`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isnotserialized(v=vs.110).aspx) off of the `FieldInfo`:

```
if (!field.IsNotSerialized)
{
    Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
}
```

It's worth pointing out that the `NonSerialized` attribute gets special treatment by the compiler. Unlike most attributes, this ones does not actually get emitted into CIL, rather it is a flag on the field, so checking for the existence of the attribute may not work. Instead, it is appropriate to check the field's flag directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Also thanks for the clear explanation.